# Finding a mapping using Repository manager query tool

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I know a particular source definition name. Now I need to know the list of mapping names in which that source definition is used. How can I query this?

Example:
There are 100 mappings in a folder. 4 mappings using the source ABC, I need to find out that 4 mapping names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the DESIGNER tool and not the Repository manager tool.

In the designer, open the folder you want to check and then open the source's folder.

After you find your source, right click on it and select dependencies , then mark MAPPINGS (you can also mark mapplets, sessions,workelts and ETC...) it will show you the name of the mapping or what ever you choose .

Hope this is what you meant.